# Creating shared object files from existing libraries

Tags: java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm using linux (Ubuntu) and trying to create a shared library (.so) from C code for use with the Java Native Interface (JNI). When using simple C code I can do this with the command:

```
gcc -shared -fpic -o Wrapper.so -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/include/linux -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/include Wrapper.c
```

However, when I try to incorporate existing libraries into the C code such as:

```
#include <rte_memory.h>
#include <rte_memzone.h>
#include <rte_launch.h>
#include <rte_tailq.h>
#include <rte_eal.h>
#include <rte_per_lcore.h>
#include <rte_lcore.h>
#include <rte_debug.h>
```

I get an undefined reference error for the methods from these libraries. I've tried giving a path the directory with the shared object files for the library are located using the -I flag with no success.

Should I be trying to link with the header files or the shared object files (.so) and which directory should these files be in?

What tool/command should I be using to generate the required shared library for use with JNI?

Comment: What errors are you seeing and when?

Comment: It is not clear when you got the "undefined reference error". Did you get the error during compilation or linking or runtime?

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried giving a path the directory with the shared object files for the library are located using the -I flag with no success.

Naturally: the `-I` flag isn't about any libraries. Please read the GCC [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html).

> Should I be trying to link with the header files or the shared object files (.so) and which directory should these files be in?

You can't *link* with header files. You can only link with object files, and archive or shared libraries.

Assuming your DPDK is installed into `/home/user/DPDK/{include,lib}` your command line should look something like:

```
gcc -I /home/user/DPDK/include ... -shared -fPIC -o Wrapper.so \
  Wrapper.c -L /home/user/DPDK/lib -lrte_eal
```

If the `librte_eal` is built as a shared library, you will likely need `-Wl,-rpath=/home/user/DPDK/lib` as well.